# Displaying icons side by side

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to display several social media icons side by side in a footer. I have tried using the float: left property which did not work. Can someone spot my error?

I have the following html code:

```
<div id="footer"> 
<div id="v_line"></div>

    <div class="social-popout">
    <div class="columns">
    <ul id="lpro">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><div class="fbicon"><img id="social_me" src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
     </ul>

    <ul>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank"><div class="linkedin_amandasopkin"><img id="social_me" src="linkedin.png" alt="Linked In"></a>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <a href="https://plus.google.com/" target="_blank"><img id="social_me" src="googleplus.png" alt="Google Plus"></a>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.social_me {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: 30px; 
 }
```

Comment: uhm.. why are they in different `ul`s? just remove the `ul`s

Comment: Also, your code is not valid, you have tags that don't end and multiple elements with same id

Comment: 1) Remove all the unordered lists. There is no good reason why they are there. 2) you are assigning multiple elements with the same ID (social_me). Use classes for that. 3) See if that solves the problem. If it does, kick your feet up and wear your sunglasses indoors B)

Comment: I removed the ul tags and put all of it into a div. They are still displaying one underneath another (and not side-by-side.) Is the CSS correct?

Answer (score 0):

Remove unnecessary `ul` tags and add `li` to each item

CSS:

```
ul li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="lpro">
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><div class="fbicon"><img id="social_me" src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank"><div class="linkedin_amandasopkin"><img id="social_me" src="linkedin.png" alt="Linked In"></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/" target="_blank"><img id="social_me" src="googleplus.png" alt="Google Plus"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CUuNA/2/)

Comment: I tried this and the icons still display one under another and not side-by-side.

Comment: Make sure you did everything right because on the demo I see them side by side

Answer (score 0):

Just correcting some html errors:

1) Remove the unnecessary `ul`

2) Remove the `div` inside the `<a>` tags

3) Your `id="social_me"` is wrong.. It is a class, not an id.

4) After that, no need for css what so ever (`<a>` and `<img>` tags are already inline elements by default): http://jsfiddle.net/M665q/

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="social-popout">
    <div class="columns">
        <a class="social_me" href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></a>
        <a  class="social_me" href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank"><img  src="linkedin.png" alt="Linked In" /></a>
            <a  class="social_me" href="https://plus.google.com/" target="_blank"><img src="googleplus.png" alt="Google Plus" /></a>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this and the icons still display one under another and not side-by-side.

Comment: Yes it does. Check the fiddle on my answer... Unless the container is too small, then you would have to add a property to the container, like: `.columns { white-space: nowrap; }`

Answer (score 0):

Put them all in one `<ul>` and the `<div>` tags next to the images was messing it up.

Something like this should work:

```
<div id="footer"> 
    <div id="v_line"></div>
    <div class="social-popout">
        <div class="columns">
            <ul id="lpro">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" class="fbicon"><img id="social_me" src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank" class="linkedin_amandasopkin"><img id="social_me" src="linkedin.png" alt="Linked In"></a>
                <a href="https://plus.google.com/" target="_blank"><img id="social_me" src="googleplus.png" alt="Google Plus"></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this and the icons still display one under another and not side-by-side.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="navlist">
<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><div class="fbicon"><img id="social_me" src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank"><div class="linkedin_amandasopkin"><img id="social_me" src="linkedin.png" alt="Linked In"></a></li>
<li><a href="https://plus.google.com/" target="_blank"><img id="social_me" src="googleplus.png" alt="Google Plus"></a></li>
</ul>

#navlist li
{
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
padding-right: 20px;
float: left;
```

}

Comment: I tried this and the icons still display one under another and not side-by-side.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you're having a problem linking your CSS to your HTML page. Try putting it into the head.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.lpro li {
float: left;
padding: .5em;
list-style-type: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<div id="footer"> 
<div class="social-popout">
<div class="columns">
<ul class="lpro">
<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank"><img src="linkedin.png" alt="Linked In"></a></li>
<li><a href="https://plus.google.com/" target="_blank"><img src="googleplus.png" alt="Google Plus"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by creating three different unordered lists. I used:

```
.column {
float:left;
padding: 10px 20px 0px 10px;
}

ul{
list-style-type:none;
padding-left:0px;
text-decoration:none;
padding-top: 10px;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.title-logo{
    color: #5E81F4;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
     margin-left: 10px;
}
.logo a{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
 <div class="logo">
            <a href="/#">
                <div class="shap-logo">
                    <H1>O</H1>
                </div>
                <h3 class="title-logo">Ohara</h3>
            </a>
           </div>
```

I tried this for my code, but I don't know it's correct or not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).